# Unable to set text to textView in OnItemClick of autocomplete text view when navigating between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, autocompletetextview

Here is the context..

When my app is getting loaded frag A will be loaded having a AutoCOmpletetextview and a textView on selecting item from AutoCOmpletetextview I'm assigning a value in to textview --which is working fine

From NavigationDrawer when navigate to Frag B (Where I have same 1auto complete text view and text box same type functionality).. when I come back to Frag and select item of autcompletetextview value is getting  to textview  because I can see in toast but still I cannot view it (its empty)..when I run

Where as this case is working fine in frag B i.e when I again navigate back to frag B from A this is working fine i,e I can see value in that textview(as I have same autocomplete and textview even there too)

Here is my AutoCOmplete OnItemClickListener code

```
objAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView objTextView = (TextView) view;
                CommonMethods.showLongToast(getActivity(), objTextView.getText().toString());
                TextView KText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt_K);
                KText.setText("some value based in my logic by passing my objTextView.getText()");
                CommonMethods.showLongToast(getActivity(),KText.getText().toString()); //I'm able to see value in toast
            }
        });
```

Comment: is `kText` the same as `KText`?

Comment: Ya same I'm sorry will edit

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve problem by replacing this

```
TextView KText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt_K);
```

with

```
TextView KText = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txt_K);
```

where myView is the view that I have inflated in onCreate method of fragment

```
 final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragA, container, false);
```